# "error: conflicting types" when trying to return a character-array reference

Tags: c, string, return

In an effort to learn C and string operations, I'm making a small program that simply generates random IP addresses as strings and outputs it. From what I've gathered from various tutorials as well as examples here on stackoverflow, the below would be one way of doing so, but returning the character array reference is what stumps me, as it doesn't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *testip = randip();
  printf("%s", testip);
  free(testip);
  return 0;
}

// get rand IP
char* randip()
{
  char *ip = malloc(16);
  int a = randint(1,254);
  int b = randint(0,254);
  int c = randint(0,254);
  int d = randint(0,254);

  sprintf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a, b, c, d);
  printf("D> randip generated %s", ip);
  return ip;
}

// generate rand int
int randint(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
       double scaled = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
       return (max - min +1)*scaled + min;
}
```

gcc output:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:18: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
test.c: At top level:
test.c:17:7: error: conflicting types for ‘randip’
test.c:8:18: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘randip’ was here
```

I am unable to see which types are incompatible? Did I accidentally return, call, or miscast a type I didn't intend for?

**Note:** Yes, I know my randomness isn't very random, and there are probably better way of handling that part, but that's outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: You need to declare the functions before calling them. Or move the definitions up before they are called.

Comment: @kalyum moving the function definitions around fixed it, thanks.I guess `previous implicit declaration of ‘randip’ was here` was the hint that the function was undeclared?

Comment: Your compiler should also issue some warning about implicitely declaring `randip`. If not, you should turn up warning level.

Comment: You should consider all warnings containing "implicit declaration" as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need the function prototype before it is called.
2. If the function does not take parameters declare it as `char* randip(void)`
3. Use the correct `main` signature. In this case `int main(void)`

```
int randint(unsigned int min, unsigned int max);
char* randip(void);

int main(void)
{
     /* ...*/
}

char* randip(void)
{
     /* ...*/
}

// generate rand int
int randint(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
     /* ...*/
}
```